# PHP Variables in Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, so here's my code:

```
$output = array();
$output['num_items_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_item'] = $today;
$output['num_comments_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_comment'] = '';
$today = the_date();
print_r( $output );
```

I would expect the 'date_of_most_recent_item' to have today's date but there is zero output.

Oh, how little I know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invert your two statements where `$today` is involved:

```
$today = the_date(); // this statement must be before you use $today
$output = array();
$output['num_items_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_item'] = $today;
$output['num_comments_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_comment'] = '';
print_r( $output );
```

Comment: Yep, you are trying to assign the value of the variable `$today` into the array before you are declaring what the value of `$today` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output['date_of_most_recent_item'] = $today;
```

At this point, `$today` is uninitialized, and hence `date_of_most_recent_item` holds no value.

You assign a value to `$today` later.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value of `$output['date_of_most_recent_item']` to be `$today`, `$today` hadn't been set yet. So, you just set it to the value of an unitialized variable--nothing.

Your best option:

```
$output = array();
$output['num_items_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_item'] = the_date();
$output['num_comments_in_tree'] = 0;
$output['date_of_most_recent_comment'] = '';

print_r( $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional point not covered yet: assuming `the_date()` is from Wordpress, you also have the issue of it echoing, not returning the value. The final optional argument needs to be set to false.

edit: the signature is `the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo )`. To me this is pretty ugly, since $echo defaults to true, and it's last. So to return the value instead of echoing it, you need to say:

```
$today = the_date( "F j, Y", "", "", $echo );
```

since those ore the default arguments. If I designed that function I would just return always and let the user echo it if they wanted. How hard is it to write `<?= the_date(); ?>` instead of `<? the_date(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks Tesserex, I'm coming across the echo issue a lot with WordPress. For instance, I'd like to use wp_list_pages without having to echo the pages and ideally sort them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't have to modify the order in which you are assigning variables.  I believe the issue you are encountering here is one of [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

When you assign a variable with a string value in PHP, the string itself is copied.  However, you can modify that behavior if you wish by assigning a reference to the variable rather than the copy of the string.  You would accomplish that as follows:

```
$output['date_of_most_recent_item'] =& $today;
$today = the_date();
```

I would say that this is probably less common than re-ordering your statements, but if it is what you want to achieve, then you can do it this way.

Comment: ah, I see the ampersand from time to time and now I know. Thanks.